# Smooth movement in processing

Tags: java, processing

I tried creating smooth movement in processing but it doesn't work right now and I am not sure why it isn't working. I am a beginner at coding so don't make it too complicated for me when explaining :). The character moves very blocky right now and I can't press multiple buttons at the same time, it would be nice if someone could help me. Thank you in advance.

```java
class Player1 {
    int x = width/2;
    int y;
    float speedX = 5;
    float speedY = 5;
    int size;

    boolean up, down, left, right;

    Player1(int newX, int newY, int newSize) {
        x = newX;
        y = newY;
        size = newSize;
    }

    void run() {
        display();
        movePlayer1();
    }

    void display() {
        ellipse(x, y, size, size);
    }

    void movePlayer1() {
        if (keyPressed) {
            if (key == 'a' || key == 'A') {
                left = true;
            }
            if (key == 'd' || key == 'D') {
                right = true;
            }
            if (key == 'w' || key == 'W') {
                up = true;
            }
            if (key == 's' || key == 'S') {
                down = true;
            }

            if (key == 'a' || key == 'A') {
                x -= speedX;
            }
            if (key == 'd' || key == 'D') {
                x += speedX;
            }
            if (key == 'w' || key == 'W') {
                y -= speedY;
            }
            if (key == 's' || key == 'S') {
                y += speedY;
            }
        }
    }

    void keyReleased() {
        if (key == 'a' || key == 'A') {
            left = false;
        }
        if (key == 'd' || key == 'D') {
            right = false;
        }
        if (key == 'w' || key == 'W') {
            up = false;
        }
        if (key == 's' || key == 'S') {
            down = false;
        }
      }
}
```

This is the main code page

```java
Stars stars[] = new Stars[100];
Player1 player1;
Player2 player2;


void setup() {
    size(600, 800);
    player1 = new Player1(width/2, 100, 30);
    player2 = new Player2(width/2, 700, 30);

    for (int i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
        stars[i] = new Stars((int)random(width), (int)random(height));
    }
}

void draw() {
    background(0); 
    stroke(255);
    strokeWeight(3);
    line(0, height/2, width, height/2);


    //draw stars
    for (int i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
        stars[i].run();
    }

    // draw players
    player1.run();
    player2.run();

}
```

Comment: Thank you I changed it so you can see the main code page as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I recommend to chang the class `Player1` respectively `Player2`. Do not use different class, for objects which behave the same. Note, the only difference is that the players are moved by different keys, this should not be handled by different objects.
Create a single class `Player`. The class ahs to new methods `pressed` and `released`, which change the current direction of movement (`dx`, `dy`), dependent on the input parameters `left`, `right`, `up` and `down`. e.g.:

```java
class Player {  
    int x, y;
    int dx = 0, dy = 0;
    float speedX = 5;
    float speedY = 5;
    int size;

    Player(int newX, int newY, int newSize) {
        x = newX;
        y = newY;
        size = newSize;
    }

    void run() {
        display();
        movePlayer();
    }

    void movePlayer() {
        x += dx * speedX;
        y += dy * speedY;
    }

    void display() {
        ellipse(x, y, size, size);
    }

    void pressed(boolean left, boolean right, boolean up, boolean down) {
        if (left)  dx = -1;
        if (right) dx =  1;
        if (up)    dy = -1;
        if (down)  dy =  1;
    }

    void released(boolean left, boolean right, boolean up, boolean down) { 
        if (left)  dx = 0;
        if (right) dx = 0;
        if (up)    dy = 0;
        if (down)  dy = 0;
    }
}
```

Use e keyboard callbacks [`keyPressed()`](https://processing.org/reference/keyPressed_.html) and [`keyReleased()`](https://processing.org/reference/keyReleased_.html) to change the movement of the players. The parameters `left`, `right`, `up` and `down` ares set dependent on the keys which are pressed or released. e.g.:

```java
Player player1;
Player player2;

void setup() {
    // [...]
}

void draw() {
    // [...]
}

void keyPressed() {
    player1.pressed((key == 'a' || key == 'A'), (key == 'd' || key == 'D'),
                    (key == 'w' || key == 'W'), (key == 's' || key == 'S'));

    player2.pressed(keyCode == LEFT, keyCode == RIGHT, keyCode == UP, keyCode == DOWN);
}

void keyReleased() {
    player1.released((key == 'a' || key == 'A'), (key == 'd' || key == 'D'),
                     (key == 'w' || key == 'W'), (key == 's' || key == 'S'));

    player2.released(keyCode == LEFT, keyCode == RIGHT, keyCode == UP, keyCode == DOWN);
}
```

This allows you to handle the state of multiple keys simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time and helping me, but unfortunatly my Player doesnt move now. I've changed the game to a single player game where you can only move left and right. I changed my code in the question but I don't know what i did wrong this time.

Comment: @Lukaas `keyReleased` and `keyPressed` are global functions. Remove them from the class and put them in global scope. This means remove them from `Player` and put them in the main code page.

Comment: @Lukaas  Note it makes no sense to change the code in the question by the updated code. The code in the question has the issue and the answer is based on this issue.